# I am trying to convert a string from a list into an integer without losing the decimal places

Tags: python, string, list, integer, decimal

I want to convert a string to integer without rounding. For example

```
s = "99.7"
x = s(int(float(s))
```

Output:

```
99
```

But I want the output to be 99.7
I was thinking of just adding all the strings to a list and somehow converting the list to an integer but I am not sure how to do that or how to even do it individually.

Desired output:

```
x = '99.7'
z = int(x)
```

output:

```
99.7
```

Comment: `int` makes *integers* (whole numbers).  Try `float` alone.

Answer (score 1):

An integer in python can not have a floating point. To show this you should use

```
float(x)
```

This will prevent any rounding.

Comment: "This will prevent any rounding" -- not quite true if you want to be pedantic. 99.7 is a base 10 number that can't be expressed exactly as a finite base 2 decimal. `float()` will round the string to the nearest 64-bit IEEE number.

Comment: :).............................................